# jQuery each() and casperjs?

Tags: jquery, casperjs

I want to echo ids of all elements that match my selector, but I get confused with two different 'this,'.

To echo something to casper I use this.echo()
But when I am using .each() this, referers to the current element in the loop.
So this doesn't work

```
$('.market_listing_row').each(function(i){ this.echo( $( this ).attr('id') ) } )
```

and neither does

```
 $('.market_listing_row').each(function(i){ casper.echo( $( this ).attr('id') ) } )
```

Since there are no errors being output it seems like casper doesn't receive the command to `.echo()`. 
How do I deal with this `this.`?

A little more context:

```
...
casper.waitForSelector('#result_0', function() {
            this.click('#result_0');
});
casper.then(function() {


        var listing = [];

        $('.market_listing_row').each(function(i){ listing.push({id: $( this ).attr('id') }) } )

        for (var i=0; i<listing.length; i++){
            for( var k in listing[i]){
                this.echo(k + ': ' + listing[i].k);
            }
            this.echo('\n');
        }
});
casper.run();
```

I have a set of div rows of various goods and want to make an array of js objects for each like this: `[{id: id, price: price}]`

Right now I am just trying to extract the ids.

Comment: What context is your code in? I guesses this piece of code is in something like `casper.start(someLink, function(){ // your code});`. Is that right? We need more code to understand your problem.

Comment: @HerringtonDarkholme, updated with some context.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example :

```
var links = [];
var casper = require('casper').create();

function getLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('h3.r a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('href');
    });
}

casper.start('http://google.fr/', function() {
    // search for 'casperjs' from google form
    this.fill('form[action="/search"]', { q: 'casperjs' }, true);
});

casper.then(function() {
    // aggregate results for the 'casperjs' search
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
    // now search for 'phantomjs' by filling the form again
    this.fill('form[action="/search"]', { q: 'phantomjs' }, true);
});

casper.then(function() {
    // aggregate results for the 'phantomjs' search
    links = links.concat(this.evaluate(getLinks));
});

casper.run(function() {
    // echo results in some pretty fashion
    this.echo(links.length + ' links found:');
    this.echo(' - ' + links.join('\n - ')).exit();
});
```